# Recommendable Ruby gems for form builder and PDF generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm new to Rails and trying to build a web app which has forms to let users answer those and migrate the data what users answered to actual PDF file.

Any recommendable gems or other web-app frameworks for this usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdf-forms` is what you need.

You could also use `PDFtk` if you want to populate official PDF templates (eg. IRS forms) with data.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.